# ¿Cómo se llama este efecto que utiliza esta pagina web? ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo usando CSS y JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ui

Acá dejo un video explicando el efecto

Consiste en que cuando la persona con el móvil estira hacia abajo, la imagen hace como un zoom y su cuadro se estira también, y cuando sube el scroll la imagen desaparece y su cuadro también

Como se llama, como puedo hacerlo, dejo un video mas descriptivo

http://churunexpress.cl/Video.MOV

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas dos cosas: trackear el `scroll` del usuario y en función del mismo, alterar el contenedor de la imagen.

Me explico. En el video que adjuntas, al "bajar" en la página, la foto crece. Para poder expandir la foto de esa forma puedes usar:

1. La imagen como fondo en un `div` con la propiedad `background-size: cover;` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp
2. Tratarla como `img` pero con la propiedad `object-fit: cover;` https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Una vez resuelto el comportamiento de tu contenedor de imagen, lo que queda es trackear el `scroll` del usuario y en función de su altura relativa al top, crear una función que altere la altura del contenedor de la imagen.

Aquí encuentras el código de ejemplo que te permite trackear el `scroll` del usuario: con esa fórmula, alteras la imagen y listo.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp

Nos comentas como te va, un saludo!